# How does the system admin gets the ethernet address of computers in the network?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, administration

I am very new to system administration. Have a doubt, how does the system admin gets the Ethernet address information of the computers in the network. Actually my doubt is how does he determine the Ethernet address before the complete network gets established.

For example, the system administrator is configuring the entire network by doing static allocation of IPs to the computers on the network. But, for doing that he needs to map the IP to the Ethernet addresses. So how does he determine the Ethernet addresses? Is it done manually, or is there any command/trick involved in it.

**P.S.** The reason I ask this question is, I don't have any practical experience doing this, also no source is available where I could get the information.

Answer (score 0):

the command `nmap` is useful to quickly scan networks.

To install `nmap`,

```
sudo apt-get install nmap.
```

Once it is installed, run the command

```
 nmap -sP 10.10.1.0/24
```

Replace `10.1.1.0` with yours

**Another solution**

the command `arp` will show you a list of the IP's in your network plus the MAC addresses associated with.

run the comamnd `arp` results

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.10.1.11               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:d0   C                     eth0
10.10.1.16               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:a6   C                     eth0
10.10.1.29               ether   00:04:ff:ff:ff:c9   C                     eth0
```

Comment: `arp` show only cache of mac/ip_address with whom is you pc takl.

Comment: What do you mean by takl?

Comment: Typo, `takl` I mean `talk` or `make conversation` or `exchange traffic`

Comment: There must be a passive mechanism (broadcast traffic, etc) that is adding arp entries... Which would ring true for just about everything else, and though I can claim that all of machines in the LAN will have some interact or talk with your pc... you can test it.... I have entries for some pc's i never interact with

Comment: And what about setting up a server when the machines are not connected through the same router, I mean when they are not available on LAN? When we are setting up virtual machines, how do we get such information?

Comment: If they are not on your LAN then there is no meaning for the question. Anyway in case of such possible case easily you can user `nmap` as described above

Answer (score 0):

To scan local network you can use `arp-scan` or `netdiscover`

`sudo arp-scan -local`

you will get output on all pc on the lan

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ sudo arp-scan -local
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
xxx.xxx.xx.2    6c:62:6d:ce:71:0c   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
xxx.xxx.xx.3    74:d4:35:06:2a:e0   (Unknown)
xxx.xxx.xx.6    6c:62:6d:ce:84:8b   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
xxx.xxx.xx.1    ec:b1:d7:bd:a2:4e   (Unknown)
xxx.xxx.xx.7    00:30:4f:18:b1:52   PLANET Technology Corporation
xxx.xxx.xx.8    00:25:22:e4:31:29   ASRock Incorporation
xxx.xxx.xx.9    6c:62:6d:ce:84:93   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
```

`sudo netdiscover -r xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24`

```
Currently scanning: xxx.xxx.xx.0/24   |   Screen View: Unique Hosts                               

 46 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 46 hosts.   Total size: 2760                                
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address      Count  Len   MAC Vendor                   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 xxx.xxx.xx.1    ec:b1:d7:bd:a2:4e    01    060   Unknown vendor                                   
 xxx.xxx.xx.2    6c:62:6d:ce:71:0c    01    060   Unknown vendor                                   
 xxx.xxx.xx.3    74:d4:35:06:2a:e0    01    060   Unknown vendor                                   
 xxx.xxx.xx.6    6c:62:6d:ce:84:8b    01    060   Unknown vendor                                   
 xxx.xxx.xx.7    00:30:4f:18:b1:52    01    060   PLANET Technology Corporation
```

`arp-scan` and `netdiscover` send `arp ping` on local network and probably all host must to answer. Arp ping work on Layer 2 and most firewall do not block this traffic.

Comment: root@xxx:/root# sudo arp-scan -local
ioctl: Cannot assign requested address
WARNING: Could not obtain IP address for interface eth0. Using 0.0.0.0 for
the source address, which is probably not what you want.
Either configure eth0 with an IP address, or manually specify the address
with the --arpspa option.
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
ERROR: Could not obtain interface IP address and netmask
ERROR: pcap_lookupnet: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned

Comment: I am sorry, @2707974 could you please explain me, why am I getting this error.

Comment: Bacouse you dont have ip address and netmask configured on interface.